# ReactNative - FlexBox UI messed up on keyboard open

Tags: react-native

I am trying to make react native UI using FlexBox. But when keyboard pops up, it messes up the UI. Take a look at screenshots and code. I think something is wrong with my FlexBox code.
It is trying to divide remaining screen space between elements according to given flex value.

[image]

[image]

```
            <View style={loginWrapperStyle}>
                <Card>
                    <View style={logoWrapperStyle}>
                        <Image
                            source={require('./logo.png')}
                            style={logoStyle} />
                    </View>
                    <View style={loginFormStyle}>
                        <TextBox 
                            placeholder='Useraname/Email'
                            autoCorrect={false}
                            value={this.state.username}
                            onChangeText={(val) => this.setState({ username: val })} />

                        <TextBox 
                            placeholder='Password'
                            secureTextEntry
                            autoCorrect={false}
                            value={this.state.password}
                            onChangeText={(val) => this.setState({ password: val })} />
                    </View>

                    <View style={loginButtonWrapperStyle}>
                        <Button>
                            Login
                        </Button>
                    </View>
                </Card>
            </View>

const styles = {
    loginWrapperStyle: {
        padding: 15,
        backgroundColor: '#7CB142',
        flex: 1,
    },
    logoWrapperStyle: {
        flex: 2
    },
    logoStyle: {
        flex: 1,
        width: null,
        height: null,
        resizeMode: 'contain',
        marginTop: 10
    },
    loginFormStyle: {
        flex: 1
    },
    loginButtonWrapperStyle: {
        flex: 1,
        padding: 15,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try out KeyboardAvoidingView which is the most simple solution and easiest to install. You've to wrap your code within KeyboardAvoidView and then add a behavior prop to it.

There's also a KeyboardAwareScrollView(https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view) which will solve your issue.

There's a good demonstration of these at: https://medium.freecodecamp.com/how-to-make-your-react-native-app-respond-gracefully-when-the-keyboard-pops-up-7442c1535580